# Using Calculus to find total and maximum revenue and profit

Tags: calculus, optimization, derivatives

I'm grappling with understanding how to use calculus to find rates of profit, revenue, and cost.  I have the following problem:

$x = \text{ quantity }$, $12 < x < 48$

**Total Cost:**  $C(x) = \dfrac 92x^2 -17x + 2700$

**Price per item:** $p(x) = -\dfrac{x^2}3 +\dfrac{23}2x + 78 + \dfrac{20000}x$

To find the total revenue $R(x)$, I believe that I have to multiply the quantity x by the price/item.  Thus,

$$\begin{align} R(x) &= x\cdot p(x)\\ 
         &= x\left( -\dfrac{x^2}3 +\dfrac{23}2x + 78 + \dfrac{20000}x\right) \\
         &=  -\dfrac{x^3}3 +\dfrac{23}2x^2 + 78 + 20000\end{align}$$

To find total profit $P(x)$, I believe that I have to subtract cost from revenue. Thus,

$$\begin{align} P(x) &= R(x) - C(x) \\
         &= -\frac{x^3}3 +\frac{23}2x^2 + 78x + 20000 - \left(\frac 92x^2 -17x + 2700\right) \\
         &= --\frac{x^3}3 +\frac{17}2 x^2 + 61x + 17300\end{align}$$

To find $x$ for maximum revenue, I believe I need to find the derivative of $R(x)$, so that

$$\begin{align} R'(x) = -x^2 + 23x + 78 &= 0\\
              -(x-26)(x+3) &= 0\\
              x = 26  \text{ or }x &= -3\end{align}$$

Since $x = -3$ is not in the domain, this means that the quantity of $x$ that will generate the maximum revenue is $26$.

To find $x$ for maximum profit, I need to first find the derivative of $P(x)$, set it equal to zero, and solve for $x$.  Thus,

$$P'(x) = -x^2 + 17x + 61 = 0$$

And here's where I run into trouble.  I'm not sure if I'm doing my math correctly or if this is just not an easy polynomial to factor.  If I can't factor the polynomial to find x, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Essentially, I'm hoping someone can tell me if my math and logic are correct as I take the derivatives and find the maxima; if I'm not doing it correctly, how so; and what I might be doing wrong when it comes to finding the total profit.  My apologies if there is a better way to format exponents.  I checked the formatting help page and didn't see any help specific to that.  If you have a suggestion for that as well, I'm happy to go in and edit the post to make it more readable.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for showing your work and making an effort to write without $\TeX$.

Comment: Thanks.  Excuse my ignorance please, but can you tell me what TEX is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $P'(x)=-x^2+17x+6=ax^2+bx+c$. First, look at the discriminant of the polynomial, to see if it has any (real) roots at all $$b^2-4ac=\Delta=17^2-4\cdot (-1)\cdot 6=313>0$$

To find the roots, we use the formula $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$that gives $$x=\frac{-17\pm\sqrt{313}}{-2}=\frac{17\mp\sqrt{313}}2$$

And now you'll have to see which root you must keep.

Comment: Would this be a case in which you could use Newton's method to find the roots?  If so, I'm barely aware of Newton's method, other than that you can use it repeatedly until the two sides are close to a certain number of decimals.  How might that be implemented in this problem?

Comment: @user1852050 If you want an approximate value of $\sqrt {313}$ then either use a calculator or Newton's method to $x^2-313=0$, but I think the former is better! =)

Comment: @Peter_Tamaroff Terrific, you've been incredibly helpful and clear in your explanation.

Comment: Please read the comment which is [written as an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438493/using-calculus-to-find-total-and-maximum-revenue-and-profit/1692779#1692779).

Answer (score 2):

When you subtracted Cost from Profit, you did not distribute correctly for the $x^2$ and the $x$ term.
$$23/2 x^2 - 9/2 x^2 = 14/2 x^2 = 7x^2
+78x - (-17x) = 95x$$ not $61x$

New $$P(x) = -x^3/3 +7x^2 + 95x + 17,300$$
$$P'(x) = -x^2 + 14x + 95 = 0$$
$$P'(x) = -1(x^2 - 14x - 95) = 0$$
$$P'(x) = -1(x - 19)(x + 5) = 0$$
So $x = 19$, or $x = -5$ (out of range)

Answer $x = 19$.